# Passing data between fragments Android Arch Components navigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

AAC navigation can use native way with `Bundle` to pass arguments from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB`. But it doesn't support passing results from `FragmentB` to `FragmentA`.

Also in [ViewModel overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) `SharedViewModel` is used to pass arguments from one fragment to another. This `ViewModel` is attached to activity's lifecycle. So in situation when `FragmentA` opens `FragmentB`, then `FragmentB` creates `SharedViewModel` to pass data to `FragmentC` and opens it, and after that user navigates back to `FragmentA` `SharedViewModel` still being alive, even if it is not used anymore. As I know there are no way to force drop `ViewModel`.

The acceptable solution I see is usage of single `SharedViewModel` for all fragments in activity, that manages `arguments` and `results`, prevents objects inside from leaking.

Is there any other way to pass results back, except usage of `SharedViewModel`?

Summarizing there is one more question. Is AAC navigation really so good, that I should use it and develop a workaround for such thing? Maybe it contains some other problems inside.